# How are the following inequalities resolved? (Using Properties of floor function)

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

How are the following inequalities resolved? (Using Properties of floor function)

> $$a \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$\lfloor x \rfloor > a \\ \lfloor x \rfloor < a \\ \lfloor x \rfloor  \geq a \\ \lfloor x \rfloor \leq a$$

---

I know that :

$$x-1< \lfloor x \rfloor\leq x \\\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x<\lfloor x \rfloor+1 \\\ 0\leq x- \lfloor x \rfloor<1$$

I can not use it . please help me !

Comment: I'm confused. I can see showing something like $\lfloor a \rfloor \leq a$ but I don't understand your statements. What are the restrictions on $x$?

Comment: @John yes . What are the restrictions on $x$?

Comment: When you say, "I can not use it," do you mean that you don't know how to use those statements, or do you mean that you're not allowed to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the values of $x$ that satisfy $\lfloor x \rfloor > a$. We consider two case: $a$ is an integer, and $a$ is not an integer (and use $\lceil a \rceil=\lfloor a \rfloor+1$ when $a$ is not an integer).

When $a$ is an integer then $\lfloor x \rfloor > a \implies x \ge a+1$. On the other hand, when $a$ is not an integer then $\lfloor x \rfloor > a \implies x \ge \lceil a \rceil=\lfloor a \rfloor+1$. Combining both these results, we get
$$\lfloor x \rfloor > a \implies x \ge \lfloor a \rfloor+1. \tag 1$$

I leave the calculations for the remaining inequalities to you. In particular, show that 
$$\lfloor x \rfloor < a \implies x < \lceil a \rceil, \tag 2$$
$$\lfloor x \rfloor \ge a \implies x \ge \lceil a \rceil, \tag 3$$
and
$$\lfloor x \rfloor \le a \implies x < \lfloor a \rfloor+1. \tag 4$$